# Cant open google maps from my native ios app with url "comgooglemaps-x-callback://"

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I would like to use google maps for navigation purpose. So I used google URL scheme for achieving the same. Once the navigation is done I need to resume my application back so I used "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" option.
I am using the below codes

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://"]])
    {
        NSString* appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps-x-callback://?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=driving&x-success=myapp://?resume=true&x-source=%@",sourceCoords.latitude,sourceCoords.longitude, destCoords.latitude, destCoords.longitude,appName];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:string] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
         {
             if (success)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Opened");
                 ApplicationDelegate.isDirectedToGoogleMaps = YES;
             }
         }];
    }
```

Here "myapp" is the URL scheme of my app.
Please check if I entered the Google URL scheme correctly. When i checked in google docs about this, they said parameters for "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" are the same as that of "comgooglemaps" expect two additional parameters

```
[NSURL URLWithString:string]
```

The above code is always giving null value and is not directed to google maps.

The problem occurs only when I use ("comgooglemaps-x-callback://") callback URL.
When I use Google URL without call back options I am able to launch google maps. But in my case, I want to use the callback option so that I can direct the users back to the source application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open google maps using `comgooglemaps://` only.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {

        NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"comgooglemaps://?daddr=%@&directionsmode=driving", encodedString];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                //do something on success
            }
        }];

    } else {
     //if google map is not installed in device then we can open goole map in web
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%@", encodedString]] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
               //do something on success
            }
        }];
    }
```

Don't forget to include in `Info.plist` like below.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>

    <string>comgooglemaps</string>

</array>
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was able to launch google maps with this method, but I want to go back to my own application after the success of navigation. By default, iOS provides a small back arrow on the top left corner which requires user interaction. "comgooglemaps-x-callback://" was suggested in google docs. Unfortunately, I was not able to make it work. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check below code for Swift 4.2

```
            if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {
                address = address.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?saddr=\(lat),\(log)&daddr=\(address)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
                let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(lat) ?? 0.0,Double(log) ?? 0.0)
                let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil))
                mapItem.name = address
                mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
            }
```

For permission and other changes, you can check answer's of @Mahendra GP.